# Python script reading db file from local network on Mac via SQlite

Tags: python, sql, macos, sqlite

I have my script taking data from the messages.log file within MacOS's library so I can get the contents of a message and who it's from. It works perfectly when the script and the message log file is on the same computer. I'm using SQlite to capture the data and Python is printing it in my console.

I'm now trying to get this to work so the script runs on my computer but the log file is on another computer using the same WiFi network. I should point out I'm using a Mac.

So I can see the message log file on the other computer within Finder. In fact, if I write a Python script that 'opens' that message log file and prints it, it does print it successfully.

But when I try to read that log file with SQlite I get

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I've set the path to be:

```
/Volumes/admin/Library/Messages/chat.db
```

And like I said, it works when I do a standard 'open' & 'r', but now when I use SQLite to parse it.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Or possibly suggest alternative ways of parsing the data from the log file on a local networked machine? I've not worked much with networking so maybe there is an easier way?

Would appreciate any help anyone can offer!

```
  conn = sqlite3.connect('/Volumes/admin/Library/Messages/chat.db')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute(
      "select message.text, handle.id from message inner join handle on message.handle_id=handle.ROWID order by date desc limit "+str(look_back))
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is it a log file or a db? If it's a log file, why should sqlite be able to read it?

Comment: Assuming it is a db, can you open it with the sqlite command line client? Can you open it in read-only mode? And are you able to share the snippet of code you are using to open the file please?

Comment: It's a .db file, apologies for referring to it as a log as that probably confused things

I've edited the original post with a bit of the code, let me know if you need more